# Python - Json & Requests

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, dictionary, python-requests

```
import requests
import json

url='http://test.com/job/MY_JOB_NAME/build'
params={'name':'BRANCH', 'value':'master', 'name':'GITURL', 'value':'https://github.test.com/test/test.git'}
payload = json.dumps(params)
print payload
resp = requests.post(url=url, data=payload)
```

For some reason the request doesn't get executed successfully, so I print the payload to see what paramaters are being passed as json and I get this:

```
{"name": "GITURL", "value": "https://github.scm.corp.ebay.com/RPS/RPS.git"}
```

Why is my payload missing the first 2 json key-value pairs ?

Comment: Dictionary stores only unique keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the problem of the `json.dumps`.

In the `dict` literal, same keys are present. Keys should be unique.

```
>>> {'a': 'b', 'a': 'c'}
{'a': 'c'}
```

Use different keys, or make values as list:

```
>>> {'a1': 'b', 'a2': 'c'}
{'a1': 'b', 'a2': 'c'}
>>> {'a': ['b' ,'c']}
{'a': ['b', 'c']}
```

or use a list of dictionaries:

```
>>> [{'a': 'b'}, {'a': 'c'}]
[{'a': 'b'}, {'a': 'c'}]
```

Comment: What if i want the same keys to be repeated twice ? Is there any other alternative ?

Comment: @PiHorse, You can't (with a single dictionary).

Comment: @PiHorse, I added an alternative that use `list` with dictionaries items.

Comment: I tried that, but then it changes the json format which I need in my parameters for making the request.

Comment: @PiHorse, JSON dictionary (hash table, object) also requires keys to be unique.

Comment: So does that mean if I want to use json, the keys always have to be unique?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47298/discussion-between-pi-horse-and-falsetru)

Answer (score 1):

You have two identical keys, `name` and `value`.

Change the names.

```
params={'branch':'BRANCH', 'tree':'master', 'name':'GITURL', 'value':'https://github.test.com/test/test.git'}
```

JSON is just like the dictionary in Python.
They are matched on a  Key = Value basis, and each key is a uiniqieue identifier.

```
x = {}
x['elephant'] = 1
```

And if another elephant comes along,

```
x['elephant'] += 1
```

But you can't do:

```
x['elephant'] = 'has a trunk'
```

Because, then you replace the number of elephants with how they look.

- http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: What if i want the same keys to be repeated twice ? Is there any other alternative ?